# Setting up a DependencyProperty in the backing store to a UI via a data template - backing store not updated

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dependency-properties

I have the following DP in my backing store wrapping the InputEnabled property:

```
public EnableDisableSetting InputEnabled
{
    get { return (EnableDisableSetting)this.GetValue(InputEnabledProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(InputEnabledProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty InputEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InputEnabled", typeof(EnableDisableSetting), typeof(EMSBasicDevice));//, new PropertyMetadata(EnableDisableSettings.Enabled));
```

I have another object structure which is populated with various parameters that us used to control the rows and columns of a DataGrid:

```
public class DeviceDisableEnable 
{
    private EnableDisableSetting _Individual_EnDis;

    public EnableDisableSetting Individual_EnDis
    {
        get { return _Individual_EnDis; }
        set { _Individual_EnDis = value; }
    }
}
```

(most of the fields omitted, just showing the relevant one)

At runtime, this structure is populated with values from the backing store:

```
public void LoadDeviceDisable()
{
    DeviceDisableEnable dde;

    // Third Line
    dde = new DeviceDisableEnable(this);
    dde.RowHeight        = 21;
    dde.DataDescription  = this.Inputs[0].Name;
    dde.ZoneText         = InZoneID.ShortName;
    dde.LocationText     = Inputs[0].LocationTexts[0];
    dde.Individual_EnDis = this.Inputs[0].InputEnabled;
    dde.Ind_Enable_Text  = this.Inputs[0].InputEnabled.Description;
    dde.IsHeader         = false;
    dde.ShowIndEnable    = true;
    dde.ShowAllEnable    = true;
    DeviceDisablesList.Add(dde);
```

So the value dde.Individual_EnDis gets the backing store value from the DP. This works correctly.

The structure shown is used to build the DataGrid in the UI. Each entry in the structure represents a column in the grid. This is the code that builds the column associated with this entry:

```
// Add a component for the Enable/Disable property
DataGridTemplateColumn EnableCol = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
Binding IndivBind = new Binding("Individual_EnDis");
IndivBind.Mode    = BindingMode.TwoWay;
IndivBind.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
IndivBind.Converter = new EMSDevices.EnabledDisabledConverter();

Binding bind3 = new Binding("IsHeader");
bind3.Mode    = BindingMode.TwoWay;
bind3.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

FrameworkElementFactory dtContent2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(EMS_Config_Tool.UIComponents.WPF.DeviceDisableWidget));
ImageTemplate = new DataTemplate();

EnableCol.CellTemplate          = ImageTemplate;
EnableCol.Width                 = new DataGridLength(140);
EnableCol.CanUserSort           = false;

ImageTemplate.VisualTree = dtContent2;

dtContent2.SetBinding(EMS_Config_Tool.UIComponents.WPF.DeviceDisableWidget.SetValueProperty, IndivBind);
dtContent2.SetValue(EMS_Config_Tool.UIComponents.WPF.DeviceDisableWidget.TextProperty, Properties.Resources.GroupEditor_Enabled);
dtContent2.SetValue(EMS_Config_Tool.UIComponents.WPF.DeviceDisableWidget.TitleProperty, Properties.Resources.Device_Edit_042);
dtContent2.SetBinding(EMS_Config_Tool.UIComponents.WPF.DeviceDisableWidget.TitleVisibilityProperty, bind3);

EnableCol.CellStyle        = visible_style;

TheDataGrid.Columns.Add(EnableCol);
```

It's a bit complicated, sorry, but there are some funny display needs that go beyond the basic `DataGrid`, so there are some tricks here to show the right things. The important bit is how the binding is done to the `Individual_EnDis` property in the `DeviceDisableEnable` structure. 
So far so good, it all woks, at least one way, but sadly not two ways. Changing the value in the UI by clicking the `Checkbox` does in fact update the setting in the DDE structure --- but --- and here finally is the issue, the backing store does not get updated, so although there is a DP wrapping the property in the backing store, that DP does not "ripple through" the DDE structure to let the backing store be updated by the UI, in other words, using the intermediary structure only presents the *value* of the property, not the property itself. Clearly I need to change the DDE structure to correctly refer to the backing store DP property, but how to proceed now, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear..... Well, I have answered my own question, clearly I had obfuscated the problem beyond easy view of it's obvious solution.

If the grid is populated from the intermediate data template, changing the data in the backing store will not have any effect on the intermediate structure unless that too is updated. So, all I needed to do was to update the intermediate structure with the new data values, and call [DataGrid].Items.Refresh() and the grid updates to show the new data entries. Of course, this may not be the most efficient as most of the rows don't change in this transaction so what I need to do is only call the Refresh method on the affected entries, I already know which ones they are as I have just updated their values in the intermediate structure. 
Most likely, using an iNotifyPropertyChanged notification I can directly get the intermediate structure refreshed when a change occurs in the backing store, then propagate that through to the DataGrid.